# Angular js: ng-repeat filter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I want to achieve is a Letter Filter. A button from A to Z for filtering the data. When clicked on letter A button, all data with A should display and the rest are hidden.

This is what I have tried so far, but the problem is in the `ng-repeat` filter it returns `undefined`. Every time I clicked on the Alphabet buttons, the parameter of `$scope.filterActive` return to this screenshot below but `$scope.active` returns the alphabet that was clicked.

[image]

Angular:

```
$scope.alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z".split(",");

    $scope.active = null;
    $scope.setActiveLetter = function(letter) { 
        $scope.active = letter.toLowerCase();
        $scope.selectedLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
    };

    $scope.filterActive = function(value) {
        if ($scope.active) {
            // return value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === $scope.active;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

View:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-alphabet btn btn-default" ng-bind="letter" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet" ng-click="setActiveLetter(letter)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': letter==active}">{{ letter }}</button>

<div class="manufacturers-content" ng-repeat="data in manufacturers | filter:filterActive">
   <a ui-sref="manufacturersDetail({id: data.id})">
      {{ data.name }} <span>({{ data.documents.length }})</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

I already tried following this article: https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

My JSON Data returns from the `$http.get` something like these, but the real data came from the client with around hundreds of data:

```
1:{id: "53", name: "TEST 0", documents: Array(5), $$hashKey: "object:34"}
2:{id: "69", name: "Test 1", documents: Array(7), $$hashKey: "object:36"}
3:{id: "46", name: "Test 2", documents: Array(45), $$hashKey: "object:38"}
4:{id:"70", name: "Test 3", documents: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:40"}
```

Comment: Does it work if you take the filter off?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman you mean `ng-repeat="data in manufacturers | filterActive`? Tried doing it and it causes a filter error

Comment: I meant with no filter to make sure data had information in it `ng-repeat="data in manufacturers"`. It appears the code should be working fine [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dre5a0ru/)

Comment: can this be a JSON problem? when I checked on your fiddle, it is really working fine. @ProfessorAllman

Comment: @ProfessorAllman I've added my JSON data on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure data is available in array variable, When you want to apply filter.

Please check following sample code

```
 //make sure data is available or not 
 $scope.manufacturers = [];

 $scope.filterActive = function(value) {
    if ($scope.active) {
        // return value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === $scope.active;
    }
    return true;
  }

  //for example your calling API

  function getdata(){
    //response
     $scope.manufacturers = response.length ? response : [];
  }

 getdata();
```

Please check jsfiddle to [here](https://jsfiddle.net/santoshshinde2012/0q7zhv4o/4/).

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Tried this but when I clicked on my buttons, it still won't work and received an error of `{id: undefined, name: undefined, documents: undefined, $$hashKey: "object:32"}`.

Comment: In your plunker, your filter function `filterData` returns the return value of `anyNameStartsWith`, which is truthy, not the obj.

Comment: Sorry I means you need to make sure your array object is exist or not

Comment: @SantoshShinde yes, can you check on my question. I have updated it with my sample data. Is it possible that this is a JSON problem?

Comment: yes I saw before getting your data declare your array object

Comment: I'm confused, how do I do that? @SantoshShinde

Comment: Initially declare your variable with array $scope.manufacturers = []; then api call assign data if exist

Comment: @SantoshShinde I'll get back to you just a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158439/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-boang3000).

Comment: hello @SantoshShinde sorry for the delay. let us continue this discussion in chat.